# What's the best place to load markers to map?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to load all markers from my List. I have no difficult to do this, but my question is:

What's the best place to load markers?

OnCreate? 
OnMapReady?
OnResume? (I saw a post)

I searched a lot, but there are many examples in different places/events.

The google documentation add a marker on the OnMapReady, but it's many markers.

Answer (score 1):

As per my working it is better to show marker on onMapReady. I am showing more than 20 markers on onMapReady (with custom bitmaps draws) which is working fine.